# I can not install a new macOS on formated MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, install

I formatted my 15 inch MacBook Pro (mid 2010), then I tried to install a new macOS, but I have encountered many problems:

First, I've tried to prepare a bootable USB that contains an installed versin of macOS El Capitan 10.11 that dowoloded from appel website, but after pressing <kbd>Option</kbd>  and selecting the bootable USB, the MBP is stuck on a blank screen.

Secondly, I tried to use the glob.  After downloading for several minutes, it also finishes on  a blank screen.

I will appreciate any help to solve this problem.

Comment: Please share some details on what you actually did so far: How did you prepare a bootable USB (stick?), which instructions did you follow and where did you get the installation image from, which version of macOS are you trying to install?

Comment: How did you create the bootable USB? As booting doesn’t seem to work, maybe something went wrong there.